# Why is the For loop replicating the procedure?

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have a UserForm that contains 20 Comboboxes and then 3 respective Textboxes next to each Combobox (so 60 Textboxes in total). Each Combobox displays the same two options (Choice 1 and Choice 2). The 3 Textboxes adjacent to the Combobox is for the Description, Number of items and Price per item respectively.

I have used a For loop to loop the 20 Comboboxes. The code that is in the loop writes the inputs in the Textboxes to an Excel Sheet in a Table format. The purpose of the Combobox is to divide the inputs in the Textboxes into the two options (Choice 1 and 2) in the Table on the Excel Sheet.

The code seems to work for the first Combobox but when I enter in data for the second Combobox and its respective Textboxes, the data on the Excel sheet is replicated a few times and I am not sure why.

This is the code:

```
Dim i as Integer 'row counter
Dim j As Integer
Dim h As Integer
Dim ctrl As Control
Dim num As Integer
Dim txt As Control


For Each ctrl In Me.custom_prices.Controls
    If TypeName(ctrl) = "ComboBox" Then
            If ctrl = "Choice 1" Then
                j = i
                For Each txt In Me.custom_prices.Controls
                If TypeName(txt) = "TextBox" And txt.Tag = "DESCRIPTION" Then
                For num = 1 To 20
                    If txt.Value = "" Then Exit For
                    If Controls("textbox" & num).Value = "" Then Exit For
                    If Controls("textboxprice" & num).Value = "" Then Exit For
                    If Controls("textboxno" & num).Value = "" Then Exit For
                    ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=j, columnOffset:=0).Value = Controls("textbox" & num).Value
                    ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=j, columnOffset:=1).Value = Controls("textboxprice" & num).Value
                    ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=j, columnOffset:=2).Value = Controls("textboxno" & num).Value
                    ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=j, columnOffset:=3).Value = Controls("textboxno" & num).Value * Controls("textboxprice" & num).Value
                    j = j + 1
                    sub_total = sub_total + (Controls("textboxno" & num).Value * Controls("textboxprice" & num).Value)
                Next num
                End If
                Next txt
                i = j
                sub_total_3 = sub_total
                sub_total = 0


            ElseIf ctrl = "Choice 2" Then
                h = i
                For Each txt In Me.custom_prices.Controls
                If TypeName(txt) = "TextBox" And txt.Tag = "DESCRIPTION" Then
                For num = 1 To 20
                    If txt.Value = "" Then Exit For
                    If Controls("textbox" & num).Value = "" Then Exit For
                    If Controls("textboxprice" & num).Value = "" Then Exit For
                    If Controls("textboxno" & num).Value = "" Then Exit For
                    ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=h, columnOffset:=0).Value = Controls("textbox" & num).Value
                    ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=h, columnOffset:=1).Value = Controls("textboxprice" & num).Value
                    ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=h, columnOffset:=2).Value = Controls("textboxno" & num).Value
                    ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=h, columnOffset:=3).Value = Controls("textboxno" & num).Value * Controls("textboxprice" & num).Value
                h = h + 1
                sub_total = sub_total + (Controls("textboxno" & num).Value * Controls("textboxprice" & num).Value)
                Next num
                End If
                Next txt
                i = h
                sub_total_4 = sub_total
                sub_total = 0

            Else: ctrl = ""

                sub_total = sub_total

         End If
    End If
Next ctrl
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm _guessing_ it's because each time you loop through the `ComboBoxes` you loop through each `TextBox`. You need to look at tying the two together somehow.

Comment: Exactly, I think so too. I am just not sure how to do that

Comment: I've provided some sample code which may help you with grouping your controls. I haven't gone to depth on the code but it may give you a start. Let me know your thoughts when you get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a problem with the ("textbox" & num) type terms. Textbox is a string and you are trying to concatenate it to an Integer.
Try converting num to a string like this ->

("Textbox" & CStr(num))

Test both ("Textbox" & CStr(num)) and ("textbox" & num) by using a Msgbox for each to see both results like this ->

Msgbox "with CStr = " & ("textbox" & CStr(num))

Msgbox "no CStr = " & ("textbox" & num)

If there is an unwanted space in the result when converting the num to a string try this ->

("textbox" & Trim(CStr(num)))

Comment: I tried both and they both work. I removed the Textbox For Loop and the procedure gets repeated twice now instead of four times.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `GroupBox` to *group* the controls:

[image]

I would then loop through each `GroupBox` and then through each `ComboBox` and `TextBox`:

```
For Each grpb As GroupBox In Me.Controls().OfType(Of GroupBox)()

    For Each cmb As ComboBox In grpb.Controls().OfType(Of ComboBox)()

    Next

    For Each txtb As TextBox In grpb.Controls().OfType(Of TextBox)()

    Next

Next
```

Note the use of `OfType`. This comes in handy when you know which controls you want to focus on. Now you don't need code like `If TypeName(ctrl) = "ComboBox"`.

You now have more control. By looping through the controls on a `GroupBox` you now know which `TextBox` is linked to which `ComboBox` and you won't iterate over the same `TextBox` time and time again.